# How to pass events as parameters?

Tags: javascript

I want to have a collection of functions in the class T, defined below.

```
function T(){
    this.Funcs = new Array();
    this.appendEvt=function(Obj, Evt, Act){
        switch(Evt){
            case "onclick":
                this.Funcs.push(function(){Obj.onclick=Act;});
                break;
    }       
};
```

These functions are stored in a array of class T (Funcs). This functions must be of the form:

```
Funcs[i]=function(){Obj.Event=FuncWhichContainsActionsWhenTheEventIsTriggered;}
```

The question is, how can I pass as a parameter any event, like onclick, or "onmouseover,..., so I am able to rewrite the function this.appendEvt like this?:

```
    this.appendEvt=function(Obj, Evt, Act){
        this.Funcs.push(function(){Obj.Evt=Act;});      
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use "[]":

```
Obj[Evt] = Act;
```

Comment: Thanx. I didn´t know that events could be used as keys.